# Javascript login, cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, cookies

can anyone help me with my homework please?

```
<div id="header">
    <form id="login" onsubmit="return member()">
        <p>
            <label for="txtuser">User:</label>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="txtuser" id="txtuser"/><br/>
            <label for="txtpass">Password:</label> 
            <input type="text" class="text" name="txtpass" id="txtpass"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" class="buttons" id="btnlogin" name="btnlogin" value="Login"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is my homework, i have got one login form , which contains username and password textbox, i have to validate the form, if its valid, Once the user logs in successfully, every page of the site will display the user's login name, along with a link allowing them to logout at any time. what should i do?cookies also required...
thanks anyway

Comment: What ... are you trying to cheat on your homework?

Comment: I'd suggest to also take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp. The passowrd should be `input type="password"`

Comment: well, i dont mean to cheat on my hw, i just couldnt find any way to solve it, thats why i came here to ask for help..lol

Comment: ive done those on w3schools, but i couldnt solve cookies, dom, ajax stuff..."Once the user logs in successfully, every page of the site will display the user's login name"

Answer (score 2):

Inside member() function, you can access the elements with their ids, then get the values and finally check for them being valid:

```
function member() {
    // Get the elements
    var user_input = document.getElementById("txtuser");
    var pass_input = document.getElementById("txtpass");

    // Get their values
    var user_value = user_input.value;
    var pass_value = pass_input.value;

    // Validate values, this is up to you
    if ( /* this is your homework */ ) {
        // Here values are OK, save a cookie with the username
        saveTheCookie(user_value);
        return true; // Form is OK
    }
    else {
        // Form is wrong
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can store cookies with some function like this:

```
function saveTheCookie(value) {
    var today = new Date(); // Actual date
    var expire = new Date(); // Expiration of the cookie

    var cookie_name = "username_form"; // Name for the cookie to be recognized
    var number_of_days = 10; // Number of days for the cookie to be valid (10 in this case)

    expire.setTime( today.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * number_of_days ); // Current time + (60 sec * 60 min * 1000 milisecs * 24 hours * number_of_days)

    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
}
```

To get the value of the cookie:

```
function getTheCookie() {
    var cookie_name = "username_form";
    var return_value = null;

    var pos_start = document.cookie.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");
    if (pos_start == -1) document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");

    if (pos_start != -1) { // Cookie already set, read it
        pos_start++; // Start reading 1 character after
        var pos_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", pos_start); // Find ";" after the start position

        if (pos_end == -1) pos_end = document.cookie.length;
        return_value = unescape( document.cookie.substring(pos_start, pos_end) );
    }

    return return_value; // null if cookie doesn't exist, string otherwise
}
```

Note that I DID NOT test this, it's an idea for you to start. You still have to check the form, set the cookie and retrieve it when loading pages (including setting the HTML of a DOM element in the `onload` event in the `body` tag). Good luck!

Comment: Of course, this is a Javascript "solution", not reliable for production environments (for that, use PHP for validating forms, setting cookies, logging in, etc. etc. etc...). Change this to your needs

Comment: var pos_start = document.cookie.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");                                           I didn't get the space at the beginning.It should be starting with cookie_name right?

Comment: @AllenJohnson I have no idea, I wrote this 7 years ago.